# Avoid redirect loop server side

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website that offers the user to enter redirects. Kind of a traditional url-shortener.

Do avoid loops I check if my own domain is entered and don't allow that.

But anyone could use another shortener to do something like that:

```
http://urlshortener1.com/dbddhkp -> http://urlshortener2.com/dbddhkp
http://urlshortener2.com/dbddhkp -> http://urlshortener1.com/dbddhkp
```

Or use three, four shorteners

Is there any way to avoid this using pure **Server**-Code (no cookies) and/or .htaccess-rules without maintaining a long list of available url-shorteners?

Comment: You could use curl to access the entered website and check if there is a redirect to a different website (allow same origin).

Comment: I agree. If you're checking a lot of URLs at once the script can take a long time to complete, but for one URL it should be ok.